# Unable to write as sequence file with spark RDD API

Tags: apache-spark

I am using the following code to write an RDD as a sequence file

```
  @Test
  def testSparkWordCount(): Unit = {
    val words = Array("Hello", "Hello", "World", "Hello", "Welcome", "World")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("testSparkWordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val dir = "file:///" + System.currentTimeMillis()
    sc.parallelize(words).map(x => (x, 1)).saveAsHadoopFile(
      dir,
      classOf[Text],
      classOf[IntWritable],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat[Text, IntWritable]]
    )

    sc.stop()
  }
```

When I run it, it complains that

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: wrong key class: java.lang.String is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.append(SequenceFile.java:1373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat$1.write(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:76)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1139)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
```

Should I have to use `sc.parallelize(words).map(x => (new Text(x), new IntWritable(1))` instead of `sc.parallelize(words).map(x => (x, 1))`? I don't think i have to wrap it explicitly since SparkContext has already provides the implicits that wrap the premitive types to their corresponding Writables.

So, what should I do to make this piece of code work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SparkContext provides implicits for conversion. But this conversion do not applied during saving, must be used in usual Scala way:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
val mapperFunction: String=> (Text,IntWritable) = x => (x, 1)
... parallelize(words).map(mapperFunction).saveAsHadoopFile ...
```

Comment: Understood, Thanks @pashaz for the helpful answer

Comment: Also for include implicit conversion, "saveAsSequenceFile" method can be used:
.map(x => (x, 1)).saveAsSequenceFile(dir)